# Removing the 1st item position as Facebook Native ad in recyclerview when adding item to every 5th alternate position by getItemViewType

Tags: java, android, facebook-audience-network

I am trying to use facebook native ad in recyclerview. But Facebook is forcing to use their method as the normal native are loaded only once. So I have to shift to the code provided by facebook but I don't want to display the first position of the recyclerview as the Facebook audience network native ad. How can I solve this in the below-working code? Thank you.

In my adapter class in public int getItemViewType(int position), I know I have to do some changes but not able to do so.

Activity as NativeAdRecyclerActivity

```
public class NativeAdRecyclerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NativeAdsManager.Listener {

    private ArrayList<RecyclerPostItem> mPostItemList;
    private NativeAdsManager mNativeAdsManager;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_native_ad_recycler);



        // Create some dummy post items
        mPostItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            mPostItemList.add(new RecyclerPostItem("RecyclerView Item #" + i));

        }

        String placement_id = "VID_HD_16_9_46S_APP_INSTALL#YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID";
        mNativeAdsManager = new NativeAdsManager(this, placement_id, 5);
        mNativeAdsManager.loadAds();
        mNativeAdsManager.setListener(this);

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAdsLoaded() {
        if (this == null) {
            return;
        }

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this,
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);

        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
        NativeAdRecyclerAdapter adapter = new NativeAdRecyclerAdapter(this, mPostItemList,
                mNativeAdsManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdError(AdError error) {
    }

}
```

Adapter as NativeAdRecyclerAdapter

```
public class NativeAdRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<RecyclerPostItem> mPostItems;
    private List<NativeAd> mAdItems;
    private NativeAdsManager mNativeAdsManager;
    private Activity mActivity;

    private static final int AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY = 5;
    private static final int POST_TYPE = 0;
    private static final int AD_TYPE = 1;

    public NativeAdRecyclerAdapter(Activity activity,
                                   List<RecyclerPostItem> postItems, NativeAdsManager
            nativeAdsManager) {
        mNativeAdsManager = nativeAdsManager;
        mPostItems = postItems;
        mAdItems = new ArrayList<>();
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {
            NativeAdLayout inflatedView = (NativeAdLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.native_ad_unit, parent, false);
            return new AdHolder(inflatedView);
        } else {
            View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout
                    .recycler_post_item, parent, false);
            return new PostHolder(inflatedView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position % AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY == 0 ? AD_TYPE : POST_TYPE;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.getItemViewType() == AD_TYPE) {
            NativeAd ad;

            if (mAdItems.size() > position / AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY) {
                ad = mAdItems.get(position / AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY);
            } else {
                ad = mNativeAdsManager.nextNativeAd();
                if (!ad.isAdInvalidated()) {
                    mAdItems.add(ad);
                } else {
                    Log.w(NativeAdRecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName(), "Ad is invalidated!");
                }
            }

            AdHolder adHolder = (AdHolder) holder;
            adHolder.adChoicesContainer.removeAllViews();

            if (ad != null) {

                adHolder.tvAdTitle.setText(ad.getAdvertiserName());
                adHolder.tvAdBody.setText(ad.getAdBodyText());
                adHolder.tvAdSocialContext.setText(ad.getAdSocialContext());
                adHolder.tvAdSponsoredLabel.setText(R.string.sponsored);
                adHolder.btnAdCallToAction.setText(ad.getAdCallToAction());
                adHolder.btnAdCallToAction.setVisibility(
                    ad.hasCallToAction() ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
                AdOptionsView adOptionsView =
                    new AdOptionsView(mActivity, ad, adHolder.nativeAdLayout);
                adHolder.adChoicesContainer.addView(adOptionsView, 0);

                List<View> clickableViews = new ArrayList<>();
                clickableViews.add(adHolder.ivAdIcon);
                clickableViews.add(adHolder.mvAdMedia);
                clickableViews.add(adHolder.btnAdCallToAction);
                ad.registerViewForInteraction(
                        adHolder.nativeAdLayout,
                        adHolder.mvAdMedia,
                        adHolder.ivAdIcon,
                        clickableViews);
            }
        } else {
            PostHolder postHolder = (PostHolder) holder;

            //Calculate where the next postItem index is by subtracting ads we've shown.
            int index = position - (position / AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY) - 1;

            RecyclerPostItem postItem = mPostItems.get(index);
            postHolder.tvPostContent.setText(postItem.getPostContent());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mPostItems.size() + mAdItems.size();
    }

    private static class PostHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvPostContent;

        PostHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tvPostContent = view.findViewById(R.id.tvPostContent);
        }
    }

    private static class AdHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        NativeAdLayout nativeAdLayout;
        MediaView mvAdMedia;
        MediaView ivAdIcon;
        TextView tvAdTitle;
        TextView tvAdBody;
        TextView tvAdSocialContext;
        TextView tvAdSponsoredLabel;
        Button btnAdCallToAction;
        LinearLayout adChoicesContainer;

        AdHolder(NativeAdLayout adLayout) {
            super(adLayout);

            nativeAdLayout = adLayout;
            mvAdMedia = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_media);
            tvAdTitle = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_title);
            tvAdBody = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_body);
            tvAdSocialContext = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_social_context);
            tvAdSponsoredLabel = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_sponsored_label);
            btnAdCallToAction = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_call_to_action);
            ivAdIcon = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.native_ad_icon);
            adChoicesContainer = adLayout.findViewById(R.id.ad_choices_container);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change getItemViewType as following for ignoring position 0 as ad

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return POST_TYPE;
    } else {
        return position % AD_DISPLAY_FREQUENCY == 0 ? AD_TYPE : POST_TYPE;
    }
}
```